# How to see and edit sections which have been conditionally suppressed without unsuppressing them?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I'm trying to make a minor fix to a Crystal Report that I have inherited.  I can't see the section that has the field I need to fix, so I can't tell exactly where the field is.  When I bring up the section expert I can see that there are several sections that are suppressed.  But the suppression condition is something like "Pagenumber>1", meaning that the section is always going to show up on the first page of every report.  But I still can't see the section so I can edit the fields.  How can I make all sections visible for editing, regardless of their suppression conditions, so that I can find what I am looking for and edit it?

I have tried removing the page suppression temporarily, and that works, but this is rather clunky and time consuming when there are a lot of suppressed sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click in the designer within a section where there are no fields, you should get a menu that has an option called "Show Hidden Sections in Design".  Click this option on the menu to enable it and that should allow suppressed sections to show in the designer.  Suppressed sections will have diagonal lines running through the background to make it apparent that they are suppressed until a condition is met that allows them to be displayed.  Here is a screen shot showing the menu with the option I'm referring to highlighted with a red box.

[image]

Alternatively, if you can't get this menu to display with a right click, you can access this setting through the File menu.  Click "File", then select "Options..." to open the Options window.  On the "Layout" tab of the Options window you will find the "Design View" group in the top left corner of the window.  "Show Hidden Sections" should be the last check box in this group.

Comment: Thank you!  I was right clicking everywhere I could think of without seeing that.. apparently everywhere except the few places no fields were at!